# Filter links in React Props

Tags: reactjs, components, state, auth0, react-props

I have a react class component which consists of a table. The table has an edit and delete button that I want to disable if user is not logged in. I have an `isAuthenticated` value that I use to check if the user is not logged in, but am unsure how I could use the variable to conditionally disable or not render the edit and delete button if the user is not logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `isAuthenticated` around like this:

```
render() {
  const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth0;
  //....
  { this.exerciseList(isAuthenticated) }
} 

exerciseList(isAuthenticated) {
        return this.state.exercises.map(currentexercise => {
          return <Exercise exercise={currentexercise} deleteExercise={this.deleteExercise} key={currentexercise._id} isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}/>;
        })
}
```

Note that inside `exerciseList`, it's getting passed to your exercise. Then, you could refer to `props.isAuthenticated` and render conditionally based on the value (I'm using a ternary expression to return `null` if `isAuthenticated` is `false`):

```
const Exercise = props => (

    <tr>
      <td>{props.exercise.username}</td>
      <td>{props.exercise.description}</td>
      <td>{props.exercise.duration}</td>
      <td>{props.exercise.date.substring(0,10)}</td>
      { props.isAuthenticated ?
        <td><Link to={"/edit/"+props.exercise._id}>edit</Link> | <a href="/#" onClick={() => { props.deleteExercise(props.exercise._id) }}>delete</a></td>
      : 
      <td></td>
      }
    </tr>
  )
```

Comment: brilliant, gonna give it a go on my end, will keep you updated!

Comment: I just modified it very slightly to use an empty `td` if the ternary is false

Comment: Everything is working on my end, thanks so much! one question I have is for the table header, should I use a ternary expression to hide that? Or is that not efficient operation wise?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I see you're new here, so please consider upvoting/accepting the answer. You can use a ternary for whatever you want -- there is no 'efficiency' hit to using it -- it's just shorthand to do an inline `if/else`

Comment: Definitely will do, one last question, if I wanted to access the isAuthenticated value in the componentDidMount function, how could I do so? I basically want to only get exercises tied to a specific user if authenticated otherwise a newsfeed of other users exercises if not authenticated

Comment: Just use `const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth0;` inside componentDidMount

Comment: I did so and was able to get it working, once I check for the is authenticated, I then perform a new axios call, this is causing an infinite loop, is it bad to perform axios calls in componentdidupdate? if so how else could I accomplish the updated axios call?

Comment: I'd have to see the code -- that's probably a good opportunity for another question, which I'd be happy to look at if you create one. For this one, though, it does seem answered and you've even removed your code. In general, if you use componentDidUpdate, yes, there's always an inherent risk of creating a loop. Function components and hooks are a good way to start abstracting these issues away and make them more manageable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66084149/axios-call-in-componentdidupdate-causes-infinite-loop